# Time.parse issue in ruby 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I have simple doubt:

```
In ruby 1.8.7:

@lablel="0"
Time.parse(@label3).strftime('%b, %Y')
out:"Nov, 2013"


In ruby 2:

@lablel="0"
Time.parse(@label3).strftime('%b, %Y')
error: ArgumentError: no time information in "0"
```

can someone explain what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's simple, the implementation has changed.

If you have a look into the docs of ruby 2 they say:

> ArgumentError is raised if Date._parse cannot extract information from
>   date or if the Time class cannot represent specified date.